# Sleuth basic tracing example not working in java

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry, opencensus

I tried to implement tracing using `sleuth-otel`. For that, I followed the steps mentioned in the official `sleuth-otel` documentation. I created a sample project to implement this. but that did't work.
I followed this [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel).

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.4</version>
      <relativePath />
      <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>demo</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>11</java.version>
      <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.4</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Sleuth with OpenTelemetry tracer implementation -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <!-- This dependency adds OTel support -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0-M2</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M2</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>spring-snapshots</id>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>spring-snapshots</id>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      </pluginRepository>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

This is my controller

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        log.info("Handling home");
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Main method

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=demoApp
spring.sleuth.otel.log.slf4j.enabled=true
spring.sleuth.otel.log.exporter.enabled=true
```

While hitting the url via postman, I got the result like this
[result image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxa4y.jpg)

I am wondering why the basic example didn't work. Is the documentation incorrect or did I make any mistake.

Comment: Please use the latest version of Sleuth OTel, latest version of the release train and don't use opentracing.

Comment: yes..i did't use openTracing.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem using the latest-spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies[1.0.0-M2] and spring-cloud-dependencies[2020.0.3].I am getting the traceID and spanID when logback.xml is not in class path.But if that file is there, traceID and spanID are missing.Please help